# Why does one of these jQuery selectors work and the other not?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
$.prev("div.a").find('.b').

$.prev("div.a .b").
```

One works and the other does not. What's the difference?

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: I doubt you are calling `$.prev` - more likely `$(this).prev` or something right?  `$.prev` isn't a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the selector works, it just doesn't give you what you want:

According to [jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev) `.prev([expr])`:

> Get a set of elements containing the
>   unique previous siblings of each of
>   the matched set of elements. Use an
>   optional expression to filter the
>   matched set. Only the immediately
>   previous sibling is returned, not all
>   previous siblings.

This means: `$(elem).prev("div.a").find('.b')` is looking for any previous sibling in the DOM Tree that is a `div.a` and returning the first - then search within that element using `.find()` for a `.b`

Whereas: `$(elem).prev("div.a .b")` is looking for any previous sibling that is a `div.a .b` and returning the first.

They are not equivalent and therefore return different results.

Answer (score 0):

find() does not search the selected elements, only their descendants ... so if the .b class is on the div.a element, you won't find it.

Find will find:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
```

But not:

```
<div class="a b">
```

For more:
http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find

Comment: @stuart: yep - @toby: you may have missed the space in the second example.

Comment: you could do $('div[class=a][class=b]')

Comment: @Vince: no need to use attribute selectors, `$('div.a.b')` will do the trick